# Redirect subfolder to index.html in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have to redirect sub-directory(subfolder) to their index.html page. How can I do it by htaccess file.

e.g.

> http://www.annonline.com/itineraries-prices/

when I type this url,it should be forwarded to

> http://www.annonline.com/itineraries-prices/index.html

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need this? Usually, the index.html should be called automatically when you enter that directory.

Comment: I have to show index.html in url too. Bcoz google reads two url for the same file: 'annonline.com/itineraries-prices/'; and 'annonline.com/itineraries-prices/index.html'; – Amit Jha 10 mins

Comment: That's what `rel=canonical` is for, but the rewrite can be done and is pretty straight forward. What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to avoid google having your page duplicated is to include:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish" />
```

in the **head** section of your page. Details about this at [google blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.es/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)

Aside from this, at apache level, the **DirectoryIndex** directive sets the list of resources to look for (see [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html))
Ej: this directive sets the resources to look for when a directory is requested

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

If you want google to see the same resource you should do a client redir:

```
RewriteRule ^/itineraries-prices/?$ http://www.annonline.com/itineraries-prices/index.html [R=301,L]
```