# redirect all routes from subfolder to subfolder/index.html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a static site in a subfolder name /blog. How can I redirect with 301 all routes inside the web directory to the same routes + "index.html?". For example:

- /blog/ -> /blog/index.html
- /blog/some-route/ -> /blog/some-route/index.html
- /blog/some-route/some-route/ -> /blog/some-route/some-route/index.html

I guess I can do it in a htaccess, with RewriteRule. I read some docs and examples here, such as [Redirect subfolder to index.html in htacess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957684/redirect-subfolder-to-index-html-in-htacess), but I dont know how can I do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside root `.htaccess` you can have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(?:(.+)/?)?$ /blog/$1/index.html [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: It works, but I get a double slash before the index.html , for example, http://example.com/blog/hola/ is redirecting to http://example.com/blog/hola//index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with RedirectMatch :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.*)$ /blog/$1/index.html
```